SPF record search flood
I have been running a Linux-based name server for my own little domain for nearly 20 years without any issues but, apparently since the advent of SPF checking, I have been flooded with TXT record requests for domains other than mine.eg paypal.com,zoom.com, uber.com, salesforce.com etc etc
My server can respond with the requested data and this in particular kills my bandwidth.
The requests come from all over the world but mainly Brazil and unknown IP's.
This raises several questions for me.
Why am I cacheing these domains?
Why am I selected as the relevant source of DNS records?
What can I do to stop these requests and/or the responses?
Thank you.

I finally resolved the DNS side of this by changing the IP address of my server but the ARP issue remains.
To avoid confusion, I will open a new topic on that.

Are you running an open DNS resolver? If so, is that intentional?

I thought that I was not but checking, I see that it is/was. I have just added an allow-recursion option and will watch what happens. (BIND 9.11.4)

also added allow-query option with just my IP range. Still open. What else must I do?

Looks like someone is trying to use your server for amplification attacks or at least indirection. Disable forwarding from outside your LAN.

Thanks to reconfiguring bind and iptables, the SPF issue has gone away. Now, however, the flood has switched to who-has "one of my IPs" queries from my router; presumably forwarded from the outside world. Any ideas?

Would adding a reject route on your router for that IP be an option?

I have no way of knowing the source of packets hitting the outside of my router. My major issue of the SPF TXT record query responses has gone away with the bind/iptables updates but I still do not understand why my 2-bit name server is being queried by half of Brazil nor why my router keeps sending continuous streams of ARP requests for my entire subnet.
